# teleop_twist_keyboard in launch file has no output

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to start the teleop_twist_keyboard node from within a launch file. I'm following the explanation at the bottom of this page:
https://wiki.ros.org/stdr_simulator/Tutorials/Teleop%20with%20teleop_twist_keyboard

And this is my launch file:

```
<launch>
  <group ns="turtlesim">
    <node pkg="turtlesim" name="sim" type="turtlesim_node"/>
  </group>
  <node pkg="teleop_twist_keyboard" name="keyboard" type="teleop_twist_keyboard.py">
    <remap from="cmd_vel" to="turtlesim/cmd_vel"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

It looks like this is launched correctly, however, I can't see the output of the teleop node and I'm not able to control the turtle.

Is there anything specific I should do to use the component? I'm guessing that roslaunch is not 'forwarding' my keyboard input to the right node, but I have no idea how to solve this.

---

update: I'm pretty new to ROS, so after investigating the topics and graph, it turns out I wasn't properly remapping the topic. This version of the teleop_twist_keyboard works, but I still don't have any output by the teleop_twist_keyboard node

```
  <node pkg="teleop_twist_keyboard" name="keyboard" type="teleop_twist_keyboard.py">
    <remap from="/cmd_vel" to="/turtlesim/turtle1/cmd_vel"/>
  </node>
```

So, still my question is, how can I have the teleop node output its text in the launch window.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348429/teleop_twist_keyboard-in-launch-file-has-no-output/) by [PeterB](https://answers.ros.org/users/53235/peterb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2020-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> So, still my question is, how can I have the teleop node output its text in the launch window.

If with "launch window" you are referring to the terminal window in which you've started `roslaunch`, and you're only looking to have `teleop_twist_keyboard` print its `stdout` into that terminal window, then I believe it should be sufficient to add the `output="screen"` attribute to your `node` element.

See also the [roslaunch/XML/node](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node) documentation.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeterB](https://answers.ros.org/users/53235/peterb/) on 2020-04-05**:
Awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for.